# How to encrypt and decrypt password to store DB in MVC Entity Framework Code First Approach?

Tags: c#, encryption

How to Encrypt and decrypt  Password to store db in MVC Entity Framework?
Am using Following Code.Please anyone Help Me.

```
      [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: See also: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html), [Never store passwords in a database!](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html) and maybe [Speed Hashing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html)

Comment: I want how to encrypt and decrypt password?

Comment: No, you don't. You might think you do, but you don't. If you *need* to encrypt/decrypt passwords, you're doing it wrong! Passwords are amongst the most sensible pieces of data to handle. So getting the handling of passwords right is probably the most important thing to do. Luckily this is a very common task which a lot of very smart people already solved much better and much more reliable than you or me could hope to. So please, for the sake of the users of your software, make yourself familiar with those practices.

Comment: Here's another great source of information: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: There are circumstances where "No, you don't" is wrong. Answers here don't answer the question on how to property store passwords that need to be retrieved. Key words: need to be retrieved.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is not to encrypt/decrypt the password, you should [hash it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480749/Cryptographyplus-aplusAplusBasicplusIntroductionp) (and salt it)

- User signs up > hash password > store hash to DB
- User logs in > hash password > compare to stored hash in DB

This makes the password difficult to recreate if an attacker gets a hold of it.